# A subtle test for color-blindness

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, methodology, vision, test

Is there a test method of proving a person being color-blind, without letting the test subject know, that he/she is being tested?

E.g. showing the person cards with colored dots like depicted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishihara_Test) is not a valid answer.

Comment: When you say the subject doesn't know they are being tested, do you mean know that color perception is being tested, or they are being tested for something?

Comment: duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23733/460

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the instructions that you give to the person, you might be able to disguise the fact that they are completing a color-blindness test. You could use stimuli like those in the [Ishihara test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishihara_Test), but instead ask the subject to do a math problem where they add the previous two numbers. You can also tell them that sometimes no number will be presented, and have a few cases of actual blank tiles mixed in with the regular stimuli. If a subject reports the wrong sum consistently for trials that involve a particular hue, you can be reasonably confident that they are colorblind for that hue.

There is also a short test developed by researchers at City University London which has subjects track a square during a movie. It's probably no more subtle than the Ishihara test, but it is less well known and therefore subjects might not infer what the purpose is. See http://www.city.ac.uk/health/research/centre-for-applied-vision-research/a-new-web-based-colour-vision-test.